# What is wrong in my tsql query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a `UserAcount` table in my database. In the `Profile` page, users can update their information. If the `Password` was filled I must update it else I just update other fields.

I do this but below error occurred:

> Procedure or function 'EditUserInfo' expects parameter '@Password', which was not supplied.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE EditUserInfo
(
    @FirstName NVARCHAR(100),
    @LastName NVARCHAR(200),
    @UserName NVARCHAR(100),
    @Password BINARY
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@Password IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE UserAcount
        SET FirstName = @FirstName,
            LastName = @LastName
        WHERE UserName = @UserName
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE UserAcount
        SET FirstName = @FirstName,
            LastName = @LastName,
            [password] = @Password
        WHERE UserName = @UserName
    END
END
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: make `@Password binary=NULL`

Comment: Make sure you supply correct value(Data Type) of Password while calling SP ,  It will not work for string Declare @pwd AS Binary='Password'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.EditUserInfo
(
    @FirstName NVARCHAR(100),
    @LastName NVARCHAR(200),
    @UserName NVARCHAR(100),
    @Password BINARY = NULL
)
AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE dbo.UserAcount
    SET FirstName = @FirstName,
        LastName = @LastName,
        Password = ISNULL(@Password, Password)
    WHERE UserName = @UserName

END
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just add "= NULL" after @password parameter.

```
alter procedure EditUserInfo
(@FirstName nvarchar(100),
@LastName nvarchar(200),
@UserName nvarchar(100),
@Password binary = NULL
)
as
begin
    if (@Password IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE UserAcount
            SET 
                FirstName = @FirstName , 
                LastName = @LastName
            where UserName = @UserName
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE UserAcount
            SET 
                FirstName = @FirstName , 
                LastName = @LastName, 
                [Password] = @Password 
            where UserName = @UserName
        END
end
```